# SpyderでPycaretの結果が出力されない

Tags: python

Pycaretで`compare_models()`をしたのですが、
出力が
`<pandas.io.formats.style.Styler at 0x27b9d124ec8>`
となってしまいます。
なぜ結果が出力されないのでしょうか？
わかる方、教えていただけないでしょうか。

**追記**
https://qiita.com/s_fukuzawa/items/5dd40a008dac76595eea
を参考にボストンのデータでやっても、自前のデータを利用してやっても同じ結果でした。

win10、Anaconda上のSpyderでPython3系です。

Comment: どんなプログラムとデータを使った結果かが記述されていると答えが得られ易いでしょう。[Compare Models](https://pycaret.org/compare-models/), [最速でPyCaretを使ってみた](https://qiita.com/s_fukuzawa/items/5dd40a008dac76595eea), [DataRobotの無料版！？機械学習を自動化するライブラリ『PyCaret』入門](https://qiita.com/tani_AI_Academy/items/62151d7e151024733919), [PyCaret 最小限のコードで最大限のパフォーマンス 機械学習ライブラリ](https://note.com/tak1/n/nb1995dafa97a)

Comment: 参考までに、Pycaret 1.0.0 を [最速でPyCaretを使ってみた](https://qiita.com/s_fukuzawa/items/5dd40a008dac76595eea) の記事で試してみましたが、`compare_models()` の実行結果は記事の通りになります。

Comment: 参考に教えてくださったページのコードをそのまま実行しましたが、外部データを読み込んだときと同じくうまく出力されませんでした。

Comment: Spyder をお使いなのですね。こちらは Jupyter Notebook を利用しています。

Comment: Jupyter Notebookで同じコードを流した結果、無事結果が出ました。
どうしてでしょうか？

Comment: Jupyter Notebookに固有の機能を使っているのでは？ IDEを使わない素のPythonで実行したら`display`という名前が無いとか`display_id`という属性は持っていないとかのエラーが出てきました。実行出来たものも、記事にあるような表は出てきませんでした。